# Bash error using basename

Tags: mac, bash, script

I'm running the Trouton script to change an Mac bound account to a local one but keep getting the error:

> Expected expression but found unknown token.

Tried others syntax fixes but to no avail. Can anybody suggest a fix?

First two lines of code (Line 84 in code file):

```bsh
listUsers="$(/usr/bin/dscl . list /Users UniqueID | awk '$2 > 1000 {print $1}') FINISHED"
FullScriptName=$(basename "$0")
```

Full code is here at [GitHub](https://github.com/rtrouton/rtrouton_scripts/blob/master/rtrouton_scripts/migrate_ad_mobile_account_to_local_account/MigrateADMobileAccounttoLocalAccount.command). Its too long to include all the code here

Comment: You may be right - Im new to this.  The code can be found here - https://github.com/rtrouton/rtrouton_scripts/blob/master/rtrouton_scripts/migrate_ad_mobile_account_to_local_account/MigrateADMobileAccounttoLocalAccount.command   Its too long to include all the code here.  Need to run this code.  I have XCode installed as wel.  thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What is the value of `$0` at this point?

Comment: macacctchange.sh is the name and its in the following directory: Macintosh HD/Users/czb/Documents/